# Mediaplayer, Java Why does my song not play when the button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

This is my code. Some errors shown when running it :

1. E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
2. E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
3. E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
4. E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
   E/EGL_emulation: tid 984: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

   ```
    playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/KISS_92.mp3"; // your URL here
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            pausebutton.setEnabled(true);
            playbutton.setEnabled(false);

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("1","first");
            }

            //Buffering
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("2","Second");
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });


        }
    });

    //Pause / stop button
    pausebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            playbutton.setEnabled(true);
            pausebutton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
   ```

Comment: Please help me. Im doing this for a school assignment

Comment: Please post the entire logcat. Also, please give it a try to resolve the issue (including searching online) before you ask.